# Can I insert variables in Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, list, text-mining

I want to use regex so as to obtain specific information from the text and I give an example with a semi-pseudocode ~ you can also reply me with semi-pseudocode:

```
list=["orange","green","grey"]
text= "The Orange is orange"
for word in list:
     if word == re.compile(r'word, text):
           capture Orange in order to have the noun
```

Beware! My question focuses whether there is a possibility to use **variables** (as **word** up above) so as to make a loop and see if there are equal words in an text based on a list.

Do not focus on how to capture the Orange.

Comment: The answer depends on the language, so pseudo code is not such a great idea.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. You want to put the variable value inside the regular expression pattern? You can do something like `re.search('{}'.format(word), text)` in python.

Comment: @DimitrisTsoukalas Do you want to search for the *exact* word? If so, why use regex at all? And are you trying to do POS tagging? If so, you're in for a lot of pain with that approach.

Comment: Because the think I do is a bit complicate:
-I have fetched different urls
-I have fetched the html
-I have fetched the text (although in utf-8 and I am not doing very well with decoding ~ I do not know why but it is not decoded properly)
-And now I am in need of some help so as to capture specific words after other words or before them. I know that there are different approaches. Although, I just need to know if I can travel with different words (list) through the text and find the Noun (Orange). I have to do that by checking all the words though because I need them all checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Biffen has the right idea, you're in a world of pain if you're using this for POS tagging. Anyway, this allows you to match words in your `text` variable

```
for word in list:
    if word in text:
        # Do what you want with word
```

If you wanted to use regex then you can build patterns from strings, use parentheses to capture. Then use `group()` to access captured patterns

```
for word in list:

    pattern = re.compile(".*(" + word + ").*")
    m = re.match(pattern, text)

    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```